# Remove accessibility for react-google-map

Tags: reactjs, accessibility

How to disable accessibility for react google map? But I am unable to remove that. Narrator is reading the map by default.

Comment: Why are you trying to remove accessibility from the map? That is important information as the golden rule of accessibility is to provide as similar an experience as possible for everyone. Why do you not want narrator to read the map?

Comment: Thanks for the comment @GrahamRitchie.

My requirement is to remove the accessibility. User should not hear the map details while he is using accessibility. 
I am testing accessibility by using Narrator which is inbuilt functionality in windows 10.

Comment: Sorry let me rephrase, I understand what you are trying to do but not **why**: why do you not want the user to have access to the map if they are using accessibility features. They should be able to access the map with a screen reader and keyboard. Why are you trying to stop this?